# How to invoke window event on control click

Tags: c#, winforms

In our window base c# project. We use the `pageinteractorcreater` i call this function  using page viewer delegate  I use for that  following code
but it works at the second time page load event, but we want to invoke it on `menustrip` item click.....

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //it works 
   pagesViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FitPageWidth;

   pagesViewer1.PageInteractorCreated += new 
   EventHandler<TallComponents.Interaction.WinForms.Events.InteractorEventArgs>
   (pagesViewer1_PageInteractorCreated);
}

private void editTextToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // it does not work 
   pagesViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FitPageWidth;

   pagesViewer1.PageInteractorCreated += new   
   EventHandler<TallComponents.Interaction.WinForms.Events.InteractorEventArgs>
   (pagesViewer1_PageInteractorCreated);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work mean it never raises the event. Use menu strip [clicked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event, instead of `editTextToolStripMenuItem_Click`. And create a method and put your code in it.

You can see the complete list of event [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).